# Is there no way to import highcharts objects in highcharter?

Tags: r, r-highcharter

just want to check, though a look through the Highcharter documentation seems fairly clear. Is there no way to import a highcharts object into one R code which was exported from another? If this isn't readily available in Highcharter, are there ways around this limitation? I'm trying to build an RShiny dashboard, and am wondering if it'd be sped up if the app itself didn't have to create all the graphs and could instead simply import graphs made by a different program.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's pretty easy! Didn't realize loadRDS and readRDS can save/export and read/import *any* arbitrary data objects (e.g., a highcharter chart). Very cool!